# siunitx and using words for small values

Tags: siunitx

Quick question. I was always taught to use words for small values in my writing, like "I had three apples" instead of "I had 3 apples". In my current project, I am not sure which of the two version is the preferred one.

Does siunitx have a switch to flip between a spelled out word (three) and the numerical version (3)?

Comment: In technical writing, you never say "It's three microohm" --- you always say "It's 3 μΩ" --- at least in my field. The usage you suggest is in prose, so I think it's a bit out of scope for `siunitx`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that this is `siunitx` scope; but you can have a macro using the package [`fmtcount`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fmtcount), like this (usage of the macro in the comments):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
% print number in words if lower than threshold, else number
% default threshold is 5, change with optional argument
\newcommand\numorword[2][5]{%
    \ifnum#2<#1 \numberstringnum{#2}\else #2\fi
}
\begin{document}

\numorword{3} \numorword{4} \numorword{5} \numorword{6}

\numorword[100]{99}

\end{document}
```

[image]